# Xamarin.Android re-deploying the application does not update the assembly

Tags: c#, android, mobile, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm using multiple test devices for development - Nexus 5 and Nexus S.

Didn't have any problem with the Nexus 5, but the S one seems to be having a problem.

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);
            button.Click += delegate
                {
                    Authenticate();
                };
        }
```

This code breaks on the Nexus S, which finds the button to be null. Thus I'm assuming it's not generating my layout properly or quickly enough.

I have tried adding a simple null check, but the application appears to be completely ignoring it and using the old assembly. Thus it looks like on an older device the assemblies are not auto-replaced when you're deploying.

Has anyone experienced this? What would be the fix?

EDIT: The API level of the Nexus S is API 16

EDIT: Launched it via Visual Studio, "Deploy" configuration setting was ticked off, so I assume that was the cause of it not refreshing. Is there a setting in Xamarin that automatically resets it at some point?

Comment: Have you changed the layout only? I've had similar issues where I'll make changes to my layout files but not the c# code and this occurs. I generally just clean, rebuild.

Comment: Nope, didn't even touch the layout itself.

Comment: Huh, strange. I'm curious to know why this happens too. Maybe it's a bug in the Xamarin Studio IDE?

Comment: im using vs2017 still happening. also thus lead to breakpoint not being hit.

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling the application manually from the device and debugging/deploying it again.

Comment: While this would definitely work, it's not really a viable solution for development purposes as the build changes very, very often.

Comment: @EvilBeer I understand. What about "Clean solution" followed by "Rebuild solution"? Does this make any difference and updates the application successfully?

Comment: Nope. By the looks of it, switching between VS and Xamarin Studio seems to mess with the configuration settings ("Deploy" checkbox was unselected)

Comment: @EvilBeer strange, I can't remember this happening to me. You may have changed this accidentally.

Comment: It happened to me as well. I think it was caused by TFS since it only happened to me after I did 'Get Latest' on the project.

Comment: @EvilBeer I'm having a similar problem - changes do not get deployed to a connected device unless I clean/rebuild before running (which slows development down significantly). What setting did you change to fix this? I'm running VS 2017 for Mac

Comment: I don't want to uninstall! I have a sqlite database with a bunch of data in it.

Answer (score 0):

Do a build clean, then manually delete all obj/bin folders, then build and redeploy to the device.