# Class not recognised as implementing interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, xamarin, interface

I have the following classes:

```
namespace Model {
    public abstract class TrackerBase : ITrackerComponent { }

    public class ClickTracker : TrackerBase, IClickRecorder { }

    public class ClicksLeftTracker : TrackerBase, IClickRecorder { }
}

namespace Model.Interfaces {
    public interface IClickRecorder
    {
        List<DateTime> Clicks { get; }
    }
    public interface ITrackerComponent : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        int ID { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
        ICommand OnOptionsClick { get; set; }
        // ... etc
    }
}
```

`ClickTracker` and `ClicksLeftTracker` are very similar in their implementation and have implemented the `IClickRecorder` interface properly.

When I pass a `ClickTracker` as a parameter to `TrackerOptionsPage(ITrackerComponent)` it is recognised as implementing `IClickRecorder` and IsVisible is set to true.

However, when I pass a `ClicksLeftTracker` as a parameter, it's set to false as if it's not implementing `IClickRecorder`.

The full flow from start to the method in question is:

```
// GetAllTrackers() returns IEnumerable<ITrackerComponent>
var allTrackers = _dataSource.GetAllTrackers();
allTrackers.ToList().ForEach(AddItemToGrid);

private void AddItemToGrid(ITrackerComponent item) {
    item.OnOptionsClick = 
        new Command(async () => await Navigation?.PushAsync(new TrackerOptionsPage(item, _dataSource)));
    // ...
}

public TrackerOptionsPage(ITrackerComponent trackerToShow) {
    ClickDatasSettings.IsVisible = trackerToShow is IClickRecorder;
    // ...
}
```

What is going on here?

Comment: I think you'll need to show more of your code to get a solution.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. In its current form the problem cannot be reproduced as it is performing as expected when tested in an isolated unit test.

Comment: Though you have added more code it does not add much more to the context of the problem. I am beginning to think this is an XY problem. What is the expected behavior as apposed to what is actually happening. Pieces to the puzzle are still missing from the question.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for you help this far but I'm really not sure how to add more pieces. I'm so stumped by this problem I don't know where to begin looking, hence why I came to stack overflow. Everything should be working, as per your provided tests, but it isn't. What else should I add to give more context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by manually uninstalling the app from the android emulator I was using and running it from Xamarin studio again.

Seems there was some old assembly that wasn't being updated correctly on clean/rebuild, and it's probably related to me using two different computers with one having Xamarin Studio (OSX) and one having Visual Studio (Windows) when developing.

[Thes issue with assemblies not updating on rebuild which lead me to my conclusion was found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482754/xamarin-android-re-deploying-the-application-does-not-update-the-assembly)